# MS Access - Ignore records if I find one that matches

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS Access queries. I have a price list with several items that I am matching to actual invoice data to find discrepancies. Let me get specific. The price list can have duplicate item numbers but the only thing different between them is the frequency (in this example it's mat rentals). Here is a sample of the price list data:

[image: price list]

The invoice data that comes in has the items listed by item number but not the frequency. Here is a sample of the invoice data that comes in:

[image: invoice data]

I have a query currently set up to return the difference in the total paid and the total calculated from the price list. The query is just matching on item number and returning the difference [Total Price] - [Price From Price List * Quantity]. Here is how the query returns the data currently:

[image]

What I want the query to do is only return a record if there is a problem, meaning the price charged on the invoice is not matching any of the price list prices. If the invoices actually had frequency data, this would not be an issue. However, since the invoices don't, I need to look at the invoice unit price and see if it matches any of the prices on the price list. If it does, I don't have a problem. In the example above, invoice #1 doesn't need to show up because the $1.80 unit price matches the bi-weekly price from the price list and invoice #2 doesn't need to show up because the $1.20 unit price matches the weekly price from the price list. The one problem is invoice #3, because the $2.70 unit price does not match any price for that item on the price list. Now, what price from the price list should I use to calculate the difference? I can use either the minimum or the maximum or the closest one, that part doesn't really matter, I just need to come up with the method and the query to only return the records that don't match any price on the price list.

Let's go with the closest price to calculate the difference. If I use that, then the only record the query should return is:

[image]

Hopefully this makes sense. In closing, what I am trying to do is take an invoice record, scan through the price list to find if there is a match on price, and if there isn't, return a record that calculates the difference using the closest amount. If you don't think this can be done with just a design query, then let me know, perhaps I can write a small method.

Thank you in advance for answers!!

Comment: So, you basically want a full report, of just the prices charged, that don't match the price list - correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a query on Report Price with a left join on Unit Price, keeping all records from the Report. Then filter out any null fields, from Unit Price.

Then your Overpayment, is just an expression, that subtracts one from the other. i.e. "Overpayment: (ReportPrice - UnitPrice) * Units"

You could probably do this with one query, but it wouldn't harm anything, if you wanted to use two.

Comment: Thanks, I have a combination of queries now that I believe works. To get the "closest" price, I first calculated the preliminary overpayment and took the minimum of this. Then I matched the overpayment to that difference in getting my final record.